# Zoom & pan with trackpad on web without clicking

Tags: flutter, dart, multi-touch, pan, trackpad

I'm trying to add the panning & zoom functionality on web & desktop for both trackpad & touch (without a modifier, click or key).

The main issue i'm facing is that the widgets I am using i.e. `GestureDetector`/`onScale`, `InteractiveViewer`(based on `onScale`)... are always working on desktop as I expect but fail to work on web: On web, zoom is fine but **the only way to pan is by a tap + a 2 fingers swipe**.

I am not sure if this is a limitation of browsers/js, flutter implementation or If I am missing something.

**Do you have any approach to implement this?**

Relevant links:
https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/36342
https://kenneth.io/post/detecting-multi-touch-trackpad-gestures-in-javascript

I have both behaviors implemented via `onPointerSignal` but it only works because I make a difference between panning & zooming by pressing a specific key on top of a simple scroll event.

`onPointerPanZoomStart` from `Listener` is trackpad-specific but only works on windows.

Web/js seems to be using the `ctrlKey` attached to a mouse event to filter pan zoom & zoom trackpad event.

At the moment i'm exploring `MultiTapGestureRecognizer` and if supported by web and not touch specific, will allow me to get different pointer ids and calculate proper deltas.

Comment: Have you looked here? Make sure you are at least using flutter 3.3. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oRvebwjpsC3KlxN1gOYnEdxtNpQDYpPtUFAkmTUe-K8/edit?resourcekey=0-pt4_T7uggSTrsq2gWeGsYQ

Comment: Hey! How did you manage to distinguish a pan from a zoom within the onPointerSignal?